# JetBrains Gogland :A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Tags: go, goland

I use the Gogland tool by JetBrains to study the go language.My installation was successful, but it could not be opened.Now I list the errors it reported as following.Has anyone ever encountered this problem? I would appreciate it if it could be solved.

**Errors:**

**A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION** (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=149904, tid=0x00000000000245cc

JRE version:  (8.0_112-b21) (build )

Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b21 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  0x0000000000000000

**Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows**
 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
 http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be solved by just that information.

Please open an issue on the [official tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go) and provide the [IDE logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files).

Thank you.

Comment: The error above is the IDE logs.The problem is I can not open the IDE.When I click Gogland icon,it will generate an error log like above.

Comment: Please understand that this cannot be solved otherwise. That is not the full error nor the dump it generates nor the place to ask for help in this case. Why do you not want to open an issue on the tracker? What is the problem with that?